# Why is my cookie showing as null in C# ASP.NET Empty Web Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Working on a Black Jack game and I am trying to save the Player's balance as a cookie. I cannot get it to work properly. When exiting the browser and reloading the webpage, the cookie is always null.

I declared the cookie as a static variable so I can access in a later method to send it to the client.

```
public partial class BlackJack : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    public static HttpCookie cookie;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cookie = Request.Cookies["Balance"];

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                PlayerBalance = Convert.ToInt32(cookie.Values["balance"]);
                if (PlayerBalance == 0)
                {
                    PlayerBalance = 250;

                }

            }
            else
            {
                PlayerBalance = 250;
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Balance");
                cookie.Values.Add("balance", PlayerBalance.ToString());
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            PlayerBet = 0;
        }
```

Then in a later method that runs after each hand, I save the cookie with Response.Cookies.Add().

```
    public void Other Method()
{
cookie = Request.Cookies["Balance"];
            cookie.Values["balance"] = PlayerBalance.ToString();
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

But if I close out of a browser and return to the site, the cookie is always null.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the cookie is always null"_, at what point exactly do you observe this and how? Also, you know cookies are user-editable, so a user can reset their balance as they desire?

Comment: Did not know that cookies are user-editable, thanks for that info. This is just a project for fun so I will explore other options but I'd like to figure out cookies regardless.

"Always" null was a bad way to put it, my mistake. But when debugging, the cookie will have the correct value as I step through the code but when I stop and start debugging again, I am not able to fetch the cookie to get the previous balance, it says the value is null.

After publishing the project, I see the same thing happen. After opening and closing my browser, I am unable to fetch the previous balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are non-persistent by default. That means as longas you don't specify an expiration date for the cookie the browser clears it, when you close the browser.

So in this case you'll need a *persistent cookie*, which can be created by setting the `Expires`-property:

```
var cookie = new HttpCookie("Balance");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

For more details have a look at this comprehensive article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx

But note what @CodeCaster already said: A cookie is only a small piece of text which can be easily modified by the client. So you should consider storing *sensitive information* elsewhere. Or at least you should consider encrypting your cookies.

Comment: I already have `cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)` in my if else structure, under else (when cookie = null).

And I will look into other ways to achieve this but for now I'd like to figure out my problem with this cookie.

Comment: Well, but a break point in the else-branch and check if the cookie is really ever created. Additionally in your `OtherMethod` you didn't explicitly set an expiration date. Please check if the formerly set date is still present there.

Comment: that did it! I think when using the request in the other method it lost the expiration date. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
public static HttpCookie cookie;
```

It will create a non-thread safe type of cookie .In mutitreaded environment it will have mess up value.

This works fine..Your `static` causes the problem.Create cookie every every method and Dump it on browser `Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)` with same name

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Balance");
        cookie.Values.Add("balance", "akash".ToString());
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cookie = Request.Cookies["Balance"];
        cookie.Values["balance"] = "ggg".ToString();
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```